# Not able to use sendKeys on the Element after using WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Problem:** The code shared below works for Chrome but does not work for Safari. I'm trying to automate it for Multiple browsers.

I'm trying to enter some text into the search bar and click the search icon to display the results for the search term. When I try to enter the search term with **WebDriverWait**, the element is not found and the sendkeys does not work.
However, if I use **Thread.sleep(5000)** instead, then it works as expected. I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Also, this only happens after logging in with an account.

The Details needed for the test can be found below

**URL:** https://naveenautomationlabs.com/opencart/index.php?route=account/login

**Email:** test321@gmail.com

**Password:** asdzxc

**The code which does not work**

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("https://naveenautomationlabs.com/opencart/index.php?route=account/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("test321@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdzxc");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click();
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("search"))).sendKeys("Macbook");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='search']/span")).click();
}}
```

**The Code which works**

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("https://naveenautomationlabs.com/opencart/index.php?route=account/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("test321@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdzxc");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.name("search")).sendKeys("Macbook");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='search']/span")).click();
}}
```

**Need a solution for why it won't work with WebDriverWait with safari**